# How to remove unique key on particular mysql table field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have assigned unique key in two field username and email. I have execute this query.

```
ALTER TABLE goipmonl_users DROP INDEX username;

DROP INDEX username ON goipmonl_users
```

It's show an error. So how can I remove unique key from selected field.

```
#1091 - Can't DROP 'username'; check that column/key exists.
```

I have username, email columns in my table.

Comment: using image is an evil. Try to copy text.

Comment: The correct syntax is the secon one: `DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name`. You should use the correct name for the index.

Answer (score 7):

Please find the screen shot to delete unique index from table using phpMyAdmin

1- Select the desired database,

2-then select the desired table,

3-click on the Structure tab, select the "Relation View" option at the top of the table,

4- and finally the Indexes option at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the below command to find out the list of indexes of your table. From that, get the name of your unique index.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name
```

Then use the below one to drop that index

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP INDEX unique_constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] DROP INDEX [unique key constraint name];
```

Please double check your unique key constraint name, use this command to check:

```
select distinct CONSTRAINT_NAME
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where table_name = [tablename] and constraint_type = 'UNIQUE';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply do something like this:

````
```
ALTER TABLE goipmonl_users DROP INDEX goipmonl_users_username_unique;
```
````

That is you prefix the table name with an underscore followed by the table colunm name to which the constraint is on followed again by underscore finally the index/constraint name which is UNIQUE

hope it will helps someone else that might bump into this issue again